# How do I adjust my .htaccess file to allow a full functional website in a subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have a website which is working fine. I want to create another in a sub-folder instead of subdomain. The main consideration for doing this is I need to install tls cert for the two sites. And since the parent website uses tls cert, I want that to cover the child ( I can't afford another for now ). The trouble is I have .htaccess file in each of the two websites that looks like this :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The parent website is still working but I cannot access the 'child' website.

**Edit:**

Although I do not think routing is the problem, I post my mechanism here as someone requested

```
class App{

    protected $controller = 'welcome';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params;

  public function __construct(){        
    $url = $this->parseURL();

    if( isset( $url[0] ) && file_exists( 'app/controllers/' . strtolower( $url[0] ) . '.php' ) )
    {
        $this->controller = $url[0];
        unset( $url[0]);
    }

    require_once 'app/controllers/' . strtolower( $this->controller ). '.php';

    $this->controller = new $this->controller;

    if( isset( $url[1] ) )
    {
        if( method_exists( $this->controller, $url[1] ) )
        {
            $this->method = $url[1];
            unset( $url[1] );
        }
    }

    $this->params = $url ? array_values( $url ) : [];

    call_user_func_array( [ $this->controller, $this->method ], $this->params );
}

 protected function parseURL(){

    if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) ){

        //return $url = explode( '/', filter_var( rtrim( $_GET['url'], '/') ), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );
        return $url = explode( '/', filter_var( rtrim( $_GET['url'], '/' ), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ) );
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the base controller class:

```
abstract class Controller{

    protected $response = array();

    protected $dbInstance = false;

   protected function model( $model ){
    require_once 'app/models/' . strtolower( $model ) . '.php';
    return new $model();
  }

   protected function view( $view, $data = [] ){

    require_once 'app/views/' . strtolower( $view ) . '.php';
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using frameworks?

Comment: @ka_lin No. I use my own custom made MVC

Comment: Then post your custom routing mechanism...we are in the dark here

Comment: @ka_lin, I have included the routing mechanism in my update as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to exclude a sub-folder from your `.htaccess` because you have a subdomain, to achieve this just exclude `directory1` and `directory2` (as an ex):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/?(directory1|directory2)/ !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

P.S: Not tested but should work